# Alfresco 4.2 Audit Filter

Tags: filter, alfresco, audit

I'm trying to filter data in the build in alfresco-access audit application, but it's not working.

I want to audit only READ and DELETE actions and exclude one particular user called synchronizer, so in my alfresco-global.properties I put this:

```
# Audit
audit.enabled=true
audit.tagging.enabled=false
audit.alfresco-access.enabled=true

# audit access-filter
audit.filter.alfresco-access.default.enabled=false
audit.filter.alfresco-access.default.user=~System;~null;~synchronizer;.*
audit.filter.alfresco-access.default.type=cm:folder;cm:content
audit.filter.alfresco-access.default.path=/app:company_home/.*
audit.filter.alfresco-access.transaction.user=~System;~null;~synchronizer;.*
audit.filter.alfresco-access.transaction.action=READ;DELETE
audit.filter.alfresco-access.login.user=~System;~null;~synchronizer;.*
```

In the log I see that login from synchronizer user are stored in the audit tables:

```
2017-02-01 18:18:45,067  DEBUG [repo.audit.AuditComponentImpl] [http-bio-8881-exec-5]
Extracted audit data:
        Application:    AuditApplication[ name=alfresco-access, id=2, disabledPathsId=5694]
        Values:
                /alfresco-access/login=null
                /alfresco-access/loginUser=synchronizer
        New Data:
                /alfresco-access/login/user=synchronizer
 2017-02-01 18:18:45,070  DEBUG [repo.audit.AuditComponentImpl] [http-bio-8881-exec-5]
New audit entry:
        Application ID: 2
        Entry ID:       58797
        Values:
                /alfresco-access/login=null
                /alfresco-access/loginUser=synchronizer
        Audit Data:
                /alfresco-access/login/user=synchronizer
```

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/audit-example-filter.html

Have a look at the "It is important to note that it is the data producer that is specified and not the name of the audit application.", I believe that's what's bugging you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the data generator is alfresco-api, not alfresco-access, so the correct filter is this:
   audit.filter.alfresco-api.post.AuthenticationService.authenticate.args.userName=~System;~null;~synchronizer;.*

Also you have to look at alfresco-audit-access.xml to understand how to build the filter.

Thanks to Axel Faust. sorry, but I posted the same question also here, cause it was making me crazy :-) : [alfresco-42-audit-filter](https://community.alfresco.com/message/807249-re-alfresco-42-audit-filter)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to consider

1. Set the enabled property to true:

   audit.filter.alfresco-access.default.enabled=true
2. Verify your [properties](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/global-props-intro.html) file is in a location where it is being picked up and read by Alfresco.

Comment: 1. tried both true and false but I didn't noticed any difference  2. I put them in alfresco-global-properties under shared/classes as usual